# Firefox image div not showing (works in chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a website which I've been working on and in firefox, the div at the top of the page is not showing for some reason, but it does in Chrome!

The div in question is

```
<div id="top-header"></div>

#top-header {
background-image: url(assets/images/theme/bg-top.jpg);
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 20px;
}
```

It has a background image and a set height and is within a container div. It seems like there is a float issue? But I have tried clearing it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might also help us if your adding the CSS of top-header.

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression you would have to look at the website. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html element has a `margin-top: -40px;` which pulls it out of view since the `#top-header` is only 20px tall.

Comment: Well I never even saw that there, I guess that's what you get for using premade themes! Thanks for your help.